# How to Execute ajax call after the scroller reaches the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm correcting working on lazy loading for 200 array of objects and APIs are provided to me to extract `JSON` from the server (by passing  index, row count as parameter for the get `AJAX` and on response I get the data and the Boolean of whether there are more rows or not). But the problem is that initially I was able to get the data of 10 from the 200 but while I set the scroll function on the `div` it displays duplicate data which are already appended on the `div`. Stucked in this problem for a day.

Hope you guys shed some light on me.

```
var listgen = (function() {

  var mc = {};
  mc.startindex = 1;
  mc.rowcount = 10;
  mc.hasmorerows = false;
  mc.entity = "requests"

  //Declared variables:

  mc.initComponent = function() {
    var entity = "requests";
    mc.callAjaxForList(mc.entity, mc.startindex, mc.rowcount);
    $("#reqbody").on('scroll', function() {
      if (mc.hasmorerows && ($(this)[0].scrollHeight <= $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight())) {
        console.log('reached')
        mc.callAjaxForList(mc.entity, mc.startindex, mc.rowcount);
      }
      console.log("scroll");
    })

  }
  mc.callAjaxForList = function(entity, startindex, rowcount) {
    var options = {
      "list_info": {
        "row_count": rowcount,
        "start_index": startindex
      }
    }
    $("#reqbody").addClass("loading");
    $.ajax({
      url: "/data/" + entity,
      data: {
        "input_data": JSON.stringify(options)
      },
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf8",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(json) {
        mc.hasmorerows = json.list_info.has_more_rows
        mc.onDataLoading(json);

      },
    });
  }

  mc.onDataLoading = function(json) {
    //this is where i  append the data from the json
    mc.startindex += mc.rowcount
  }

  return mc;
})()

listgen.initComponent();
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexandra for editing my question readable for others.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll is a very high-frequent event, so I think that you have several ajax calls with same data before actually your onDataLoading called, and range incremented. So I whould add mutex.

```
  // ... 
  mc.loaging = false; // mutex

  $("#reqbody").on('scroll', function(){
      if(mc.hasmorerows && ($(this)[0].scrollHeight<=$(this).scrollTop()+$(this).innerHeight())){
          console.log('reached')
          if (!mc.loading) // add check here
             mc.callAjaxForList(mc.entity,mc.startindex,mc.rowcount);
      }
       console.log("scroll");
      })
  }
   mc.callAjaxForList= function(entity,startindex,rowcount){ 
    // ...
    mc.loading = true;
     $.ajax({
       // ... 
       success:function(json){
            mc.hasmorerows=json.list_info.has_more_rows
            mc.onDataLoading(json)  ;  
            mc.loading = false;
        },
        error: ()=> mc.loading = false
      });
    }
```

So our mc.loading will tell us if ajax already completed (do not forget to reset it's value on ajax error)

Comment: does it mean that scroll event should be placed inside the module or on the int function? @2oppin

Comment: it doesn't matter, it just need to be called only once, and it should "see" your "mc" variable.

Comment: Thank you for your insight and tried the way you suggest,but i was able to get the data of 70 out of 154 objects from json.is there any problem with the finding the div scrolling position? @2oppin

Comment: Found it! it seems i need to round off the div's scrollHeight,scrollTop and innerHeight .Thank you @2oppin for your help.